# Make an Inbox block for privatemsg

Tags: 7, blocks, privatemsg

### Question

I would like to make a block for printing messages from the user.

I already have a snippet of code which print me the last 5 messages, but I want to add more information like the author and the date.

### Snippet of code

```
global $user;

$query = _privatemsg_assemble_query('list', $user, 'inbox');

$list = array();
$count=0;
foreach ($query->execute() as $thread) {
  if ($count <=5) {
    $list[] = l($thread->subject, 'messages/view/'. $thread->thread_id);
    $count++;
  } else { 
    break;
  }
}
 if ($list) { 
  print theme('item_list', array('items'=>$list));
}
   else {
echo '<p>You still have no message yet</p>';
}
```

Comment: So you have already retrieved the messages (referred to as `$thread` in the foreach loop) and you are able to build a list from that. That seems like a good start. What did you try so far to get the other data? What else is in the `$thread` object besides a subject and thread_id? Do you know how to use a debugger, set a breakpoint, and inspect variables?

Answer (score 0):

Using `print_r($thread);` in your code gives this.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [thread_id] => 2
    [subject] => Testing
    [last_updated] => 1443004733
    [has_tokens] => 0
    [is_new] => 0
    [last_reply_to_mid] => 2
    [participants] => user_187,user_298
)
```

The below gives an array of the participants names.

```
    $participants = $thread->participants;
    $msg_users = explode(",",$participants);
    $prefix = 'user_';

    $authors = array();
    foreach ($msg_users as $msg_user) {
        if (substr($msg_user, 0, strlen($prefix)) == $prefix) {
        $msg_user = substr($msg_user, strlen($prefix));
        $msg_user_names = user_load($msg_user)->name;
        $authors[] = $msg_user_names;
    }
}
```

And something like the below gives  the date.

```
print date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", $thread->last_updated);
```

I'm sure you can work out what to based on that.

ps. I've wanted this exact thing so thanks for the snippet :)

Comment: Hi, I'm so noob in php I've installed the module [Privatemsg block](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg_block) which do the job. I hid every content I don't need with "display:none" classes. Not proper ... but  fit my needs. Thanks you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Niall Murphy pretty much summed up everything the OP wanted, but I was looking for the ability to also get the **body** of the message. So for those who are looking for a solution to get the body (or something else related to the thread), here's what I found.

This answer proved to be a great start: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/220672/61171

As described there, you can use the *privatemsg_thread_load()* function to load the entire thread/message array and get pretty much everything you need.

So I used the code in the OP's example to get the thread id and in the loop I loaded the thread with this:

```
$threadArray = privatemsg_thread_load($thread->thread_id, $account = NULL, $start = NULL, $useAccessDenied = FALSE);
```

You can tidy that up to fit your needs. But anyway, now if you do:

```
print_r($threadArray)
```

you will see the whole thread array and pick up what you need. For example to get the body, just go:

```
$body = $threadArray['messages'][$thread->thread_id]->body;
```